# gcc can't find -lX11

Tags: c, gcc, ld, linuxbrew

I've used linuxbrew to install gcc 5.3 on a machine on which I don't have sudo access. I now want to link with X11:

```
> gcc test.c -lX11
ld: cannot find -lX11
```

I've checked that `libX11.so` exists in `/usr/lib64/` which is on the compiler's `LIBRARY_PATH`. If I use the system's `gcc` it works fine, but I need a newer version to compile my actual program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/issues/11#issuecomment-216450591) comment by a linuxbrew developer,

> linuxbrewed gcc removes `/usr/lib64` from the library path because mixing system libraries with brewed libraries creates havoc.

The solution is to `brew install linuxbrew/xorg/xorg`.

Answer (score 1):

use `-L` flag, like this `-L/usr/lib64`, or you can specify full path to library like this `gcc test.c /usr/lib64/libX11.so`

Comment: So `gcc test.c /usr/lib64/libX11.so` works, but `gcc test.c -L/usr/lib64 -lX11` does not.